# clang.exe : error : no such file or directory in Visual Studio 2015 cross-platform template

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform

I installed the VS 2015 Cross-Platform tools and created a new project using the Native-Activity Application (Android) template.  I then tried to compile the application with no changes.  I get the following errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Android1.NativeActivity, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
1>  ANT_HOME=C:\apache-ant-1.9.6
1>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_65
1>  NDK_ROOT=C:\android-ndk-r14b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r14b
1>  pch.h
1>clang.exe : error : no such file or directory: 'C:UsersTomdocumentsvisual studio 2015ProjectsAndroid1Android1Android1.NativeActivitypch.h'
1>clang.exe : error : no input files
```

I noticed that, on the "no such file or directory:" line, the file it is looking for looks like the full path to pch.h with all of the "\" characters removed.  How do I prevent this from happening?  It seems like this is an artifact of using clang.exe on a windows platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same problem and could resolve it when I switched from "android-ndk-r14b" to the "android-ndk-r13b". Maybe it works also with older versions of Android NDK, but I haven't tried.

My guess is that "clang.exe" version from "android-ndk-r14b" expects escape symbol before backslash in the file path - "C:\\Users\\Documents..." instead of  "C:\Users\Documents..."

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work in my case. So further answers are appreciated ;)

Comment: I've tried VS2017 Community with all NDK version starting from 13 and above. NDK-r13b works fine. All other NDK versions have described problems. I've tested NDKs from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html

Comment: Thank you for this. I have the same issue with NDK R15c. When using msbuild to compile a native C project (vcxproj project file in VS), it will remove all backslashes from source file paths and complain that the files can't be found. Switching back to R13b makes it work. For VS cross-platform C++, it is configured in ``Tools / Options / Cross-Platform / C++ / Android``.